# (Ecommerce analytics debug) "_gaq.push processing" but no "Tracking beacon sent!"

Tags: debugging, analytics

Installed Google's `ga.js` code onto my ecommerce website and I'm tracking views and visitors no problem. But I'm not sure if I've incorporated the ecommerce tracking code right on my site.

When I run a test checkout and 'buy' and get to my success page, I see:

```
_gaq.push processing "_addTrans" for args: "[12,StoreName,0.0200,,,SomeTown,SomeCounty,USA]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_addItem" for args: "[12,banana,Bananas,,0.01,2]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_set" for args: "[currencyCode,USD]":  ga_debug.js:24
```

Which means that the code is pushing data. But there's no "Tracking beacon sent!" notification. If it helps I have used OpenCart and torn it to pieces to fit my specifications, and [here's a link to a pastebin dump of the code](http://pastebin.com/Nm6sSp1v) I use on the success.tpl page after the user has paid.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was missing a crucial line of code in my success.tpl file. The problem is now fixed.

```
$tracking_info .= "_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);";
```

Note that this is after the typical `ga.js` tracking code, which is in the header of the page.

For future visitors coming across this page who are stuck with a similar problem [here is a link to the full transaction tracking code](http://pastebin.com/KTYyaeGi) I put in my success.tpl file. Hope it helps.